# How to use glRotatef()

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am new to LWJGL but am slowly learning. I was wanting to make a square that rotated when you pressed the key. Like d rotates it 90 degrees as you can tell below, but when I use glRotatef(); it gives me an error and I don't know why. There error tells me I need to create a method for it, I know I don't need to though. Anything helps!

```
public class MainPlayer {

private Draw draw;
private int rotation;

private float WIDTH = (float) (Display.getWidth() * 0.1);
private float HEIGHT = (float) (WIDTH / 2);
private float x = Display.getWidth() / 2 - WIDTH / 2;
private float y = Display.getHeight() / 2 - HEIGHT / 2;

public MainPlayer(){
    draw = new Draw(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

public void update(){

}

public void render(){

        glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        glRotatef(rotation,0,0,1);
        draw.render();

}

public void getInput(){
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)){
        rotation = 0;
    }
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)){
        rotation = 180;
    }
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)){
        rotation = 270;
    }
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)){
        rotation = 90;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well, what error? How are we supposed to help if we don't even know the problem?

Comment: I guess it all depends on what "THE ERROR" is?

Comment: Hmmmm... why are you using deprecated API in the first place?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12027546/1418097) is good summary

Comment: @SargeBorsch It could be an university assignment, I'm also stuck with LWJGL and OpenGL 1.1 at university for my assignment :( Quite sad yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You create an `int rotation` and I assume your `render()` loops the whole time, and you only *set* `rotation` in `getInput()`.

So I am **assuming** that you should declare it as `int rotation = 0`.

Comment: I thought things got zero init'ed in Java?

Comment: @paulm Well, then my assumption was wrong. Confused it with `Object`s I guess, but cannot answer without knowing the error then.

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that you haven't statically imported `glRotatef`

Either use

```
GL11.glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);
```

or import it at the beginning of your program with

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glRotatef
```

Answer (score 0):

glRotatef() is a OpenGL call to rotate objects, just like glTranslatef() moves them. glRotatef() does it in the same way.

glRotatef(AngleOfRotationf, 0, 1, 0) would rotate it horisontally, like in this video i just made: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHsssrj9qr8& uses that line to rotate a ship.

Also in that video i demonstrated moving it with glTranslatef().

To use it you must use GL11.glRotatef(), or import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;